How can a landlord receive rent in cash using Western Union?
I have a crazy renter for a property that I inherited.  And this renter can only pay cash to me, and doesn't have a bank account, or smartphone, and is a little bit on the dumb side.
I was thinking of using Western Union to receive the rent from him by filling out the forms for him every month and mailing it to him to drop off at the local Western Union along with his cash payment.
When I looked at the Western Union money send form available at a Western Union location, I noticed there's an "optional service for sending" called  "I want the money sent to a mobile" on the form where the landlord could put his cellphone number.
Does anybody know how this option works?  Do I still need to ask the renter for the "Money Transfer Control Number" over the phone?
Any advice would be appreciated.

You trust them to operate western Union correctly? Given your description, I would instead be seeking a different tenant.

I inherited the tenant... I don't see any reason to do that without giving him a chance..

Do you not have anyone who can act as an agent near the property and collect the cash? Who do you have who can sort out other problems?

How did the previous landlord handle it?

Which country??

When I saw this title I was sure this was gonna be one of them scam questions.

This sounds complicated.
Instead get an agent. Not necessarily a professional agent, but someone who can act for you locally. If you inherited the property you must have known the person/people who left it to you. Pick someone they knew to be trustworthy and who wants a bit of extra money and is prepared to sort out problems. One of their jobs will be to collect the money every month, take their cut (you will have to pay them a little bit at least) and forward the rest to you.
Their other jobs will include some of: assessing exactly what needs to be done when the tenant says something is not working; doing minor maintenance stuff (changing lightbulbs, etc.); finding reliable people to do more major maintenance; checking that the tenant isn't damaging the building or violating the lease conditions.

You need someone who can visit the property to supervise maintenance and repair anyway...

Is this property local to you?  Do you want to keep it?  Is there a lease?
One thing you could do, after arrangements with the renter, is open a bank account where the renter could deposit the money.  The bank will likely have to be convenient for the renter.  Just send them 12 deposit slips with the account number.  As an added measure of safety, I'd open a new account that is separate from your main checking/savings account.
If there is no lease agreement, get one in place ASAP.
If the property is not local to you, then you may just want to liquidate it.  Also if you don't have an interest in being in the rental business.  It isn't for everyone, and renters can be a pain as you are discovering.

First time I've heard of "deposit slips". Where I am, one can just tell the teller the account number, maybe tell them the name of the recipient so they can confirm it's the right one, give them the money, and that's it. Looking online, "deposit slips" just seem like a prettier scrap of paper to jot down the account number. They're probably not required, which might be good if the landlord is not near these banks (e.g. they're in another country).

@JoL You are correct. They are not required.  I think the idea here is to make it as simple as possible for the 'not smart' renter. If they accidentally deposit it to the wrong account, the renter would likely need to resolve that as the landlord wasn't the depositor and isn't the owner of the incorrect account.

When I was in a similar situation (not in the US) - renter with no bank account, since they just came to the country - they would just deposit cash at an ATM, and state my account number. Though the renter was very resourceful and not " on the dumb side" at all...

This sounds like a shady excuse, or at worst, a scam.
It is easy enough for a person with cash to get a postal money order.  They cost 2 dollars.  I would suggest he pay that way and physically mail you a check.
I get where you want to do it all electronically, but first, that is exactly what scammers do, so if the person is at all wise, they will be apprehensive, i.e. the tenant's friends would be entirely reasonable to warn them about paying you that way -- and second there are ways you can be scammed or tricked that way.
The Postal Service will stand behind their money orders.

This does not seem correct, since if it is a scam, it'd be Western Union scamming the landlord.

@Allure I think Harper is saying that "Please pay using WU" might sound like a scam to the tenant (esp. if the two haven't met), so using a postal money order would be better.

@TripeHound The tenant knows that he's unusual in not having a back account that he can write checks from. He had a special arrangement with the hold landlord, but they've passed away.

Nitpick: Postal money orders cost $2. That said, there is no suggestion of any scam in the question. The tenant apparently pays the rent, but doing it by Western Union seems complicated. The tenant can get a money order not only from the post office, but from many supermarkets and convenience stores. I like that solution.

I think you're wrong here. The tenant is going to send money to the landlord for a tangible benefit (rent on a property they're staying in). There's no real scope here for the person sending the money to commit fraud. Are you just seeing the words "Western Union" and making an assumption without really reading the post?

@Valorum The tenant is cognitively impaired. #1 you're normalizing WU as a way to pay, which is doing them no favor.  #2 it's non-reversible, so no way to clawback if anything goes wrong or is hacked.  That's WHY it's loved by scammers.

@Harper-ReinstateMonica - Sure, but millions of people use it perfectly safely every year too

@Valorum Same with oxycodone, but that doesn't mean I'm going to recommend it when better-reputed alternatives are workable.
